# Файлы сайта с расширением .vue

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, vue3, веб-сайт

Нашел сайт [Сделано с помощью Vue.js](https://madewithvuejs.com/websites). Скачал сайт Aroundsound с этого сайта. Внутри папки скачанного сайта файлов с расширением `.vue` нет. Или они создаются и перекомпилируются в `.js`? (где они?) Вот файлы, относящиеся к скачанному сайту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить... а как вы его скачали?) По описанию, тот сайт laravel+vuejs...

Comment: @Jour зашел на https://aroundsound.com/?ref=madewithvuejs.com и скачал страницу.

Comment: Логично, что вы скачали скомпилированный вебпаком бандл, а не исходники

Comment: @andreymal т. е. правильно я понял, что файлы с расширением vue скомпилировались (т. е. собрались) в js файлы?

Answer (score 0):

Vue - лишь фреймворк, который в дальнейшем переделывает все под стандарт html + css + js. Браузер понятия не имеет, как устроена сама архитектура проекта, он видит только итоговый "переделанный" результат. Файлов с разрешением `.vue` там быть не может

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/765616)

Comment: @yeasyh где vue файлы или они компилируются в js файлы?

Comment: @Сергей может быть вы проясните?

Comment: Влад, не проясню. Замечание сделано в рамках стандартной проверки сообщений потенциально низкого качества. Вижу, что ответа нет на основной вопрос.

Comment: @vladwebsearch vue файлы переделались в файлы html и javascript

Answer (score 0):

Браузер может запускать только* HTML, CSS и JavaScript.

Vue - это фреймворк, написанный на JavaScript. Файлы `.vue` - это "сырые" файлы, которые специальная программа должна обработать и на выходе выдать машинные `.js` файлы, которые и будут работать.

Т. е. приложения "на vue" разрабатываются следующим образом:

1. Разработчик пишет код в файлах `.vue`
2. Некоторая программа перемалывает `.vue` файлы и генерирует файлы `.js`
3. Файлы `.js` загружаются на сервер
4. При заходе на сайт, вы получаете `.js` файлы, которые и запускает браузер.

Так работает не только Vue, но и все без исключения фреймворки.

Процесс "перемалывания" файлов .vue в файлы `.js` называется "сборка", а программа, которая осуществляет сборку - "сборщиком".
Сборка !== компиляция, хоть и довольно похоже.
"Перемолотое" приложение - это билд или бандл.
А файлы `.vue` - это "исходный код".
Исходный код хранится в защищенных хранилищах без доступа для посторонних.
За исключением проектов с [открытым исходным кодом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Сам по себе, билд представляет мало ценности. Там оптимизированная нечитабельная мешанина из `.js`.

Судя по всему, вы хотите получить код клиентской части некоего веб-приложения.
Вы видите немного негативный отклик из-за того, что ваши действия похожи на попытку своровать код клиентской части.
Может, вы просто хотите изучить структуру понравившегося проекта в учебных целях.

Если вы хотите просто своровать - я вас разочарую, этот билд нужно ещё привести в читабельный вид.
На сегодняшний день можно облегчить себе этот адский труд специализированными инструментами, но в большинстве случаем дешевле и быстрее сделать с нуля.
Для приведения в читабельный вид вам нужен очень опытный разработчик, которому нужно будет заплатить много денег, но даже при этом результат не гарантирован.

Если же вы просто учитесь, вы можете [поискать на GitHub исходники проектов, сделанных на Vue](https://github.com/search?q=import+Vue+from+%27vue%27&type=code).
Или ознакомится с [замечательными примерами на сайте vuejs.org](https://vuejs.org/examples/)

**Это может сбить с толку, но браузер умеет ещё запускать WASM, но там много нюансов и в вашем случае не важно, упомянуто мною только для полноты справки.*